# Dynamically create entire page, including scripts and styles

Tags: javascript

I'm playing around with the following code. The intention is to open a new window and create a basic document from scratch, rather than loading it from file.

```
function openNew() {
    var win = window.open('', 'new') ;

    win.document.write('<html><head><title>New</title></head><body><div id="wrap">Hello World</div></body></html>') ;

    var head = win.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] ;

    var style = win.document.createElement('link') ;
    style.rel = "stylesheet" ;
    style.type = "text/css" ;
    style.href = "/css/main.css" ;
    head.appendChild(style) ;

    var script = win.document.createElement('script') ;
    script.type = "text/javascript" ;
    script.src = "/js/main.js" ;
    head.appendChild(script) ;

    return false ;
}
```

The `document.write` part seems to work, but the rest does nothing. Or at least nothing that I can tell, I get no errors or anything. I tried to just write the script part in the `document.write` with the rest of the document but that didn't help. Also tried using `innerHTML` instead of `write()` but that didn't work at all, nor did creating the whole document (html, head and body tags) with `createElement`.

If it has any importance, the script that needs to be loaded is the same one that does the opening in the first place. I don't know if that somehow creates a conflict though I'm not sure why it would do that. Just mentioning it for good measure.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: What's the purpose of creating entire page ???

Comment: @miqbal To allow the user to open the current page, but without all the clutter of the page design. Just the essential scripted content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying closing the document, before accessing it.

```
var win = window.open('...');
win.document.open();
win.document.write('...');
win.document.close();
```

Other option is to build up the string and just add it all at once and not append to it.

Comment: For others' reference, see notes at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.open and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.close ... `document.open` will result in clearing the current document.